# How to add an onclick method on dynamically created button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching data from a php file using ajax. Looping through json object and creating buttons using ajax. I want to add an onclick event on that dynamically created button so that i can call a function, pass the current ID of the record to it, and then do some things to it like deleting or updating.

```
'<button type="button" onclick="test()" id="btnHistory" class="btn btn-success">History</button> '
```

but it leaves me an error saying the test function isn't defined.

[image]

here's my whole code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",   
    url: "../php_scripts/getUnits.php",
    success: function(data){
        var items = JSON.parse(data);

        /*var btnSomething = $("<button>")
        .attr('class', 'btn btn-danger')
        .attr('id', 'asdf')
        .html('Save');
*/


//$('#content').append(btnSomething);

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            //test();
            $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + items[i].unitId + '</td><td>'+
             items[i].pcName +'</td><td>'+ items[i].user + '</td><td>'+ 
             items[i].department+'</td><td>'+items[i].location+ '</td><td>'+ 
             items[i].dateAssigned + '</td><td>' + items[i].status +'</td><td>' +
             '<button type="button" onclick="test()" id="btnHistory" class="btn btn-success">History</button> ' + 
             '<button id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> ' +
             '<button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> ' + 
             '</td></tr>');
        }

        function test(){
            alert('test');
        }

        /*$(document).on("click", "#btnHistory", function(){
          alert ('History clicked ');
        });*/

    }
});
```

Comment: as the error says you dont have the test function

Comment: but it's defined there.. 
also before appending the data to my table, I called the test function. Works perfect but when I'm calling it to my button's onclick event it's undefined

Comment: you have it inside document ready?move it out

Comment: @guradio it freaking worked!!! I can't thank you enough for noticing it.. but why did it work when it's outside the document ready?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @voidnull because of a little thing called 'scope' :)

Comment: it is `scope` issue mate. check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript#toc-lexical-scope) you can find more in there

Comment: @GovindSamrow not a duplicate as this uses `onclick=`

Comment: @voidnull `function test()` is defined within the *scope* of the `$.ajax success:` callback - ie it's what other languages call `private` to that function - it can't be seen *outside* that function.   You're attempting to call it from the *global scope*, which is outside the ajax success callback, so your `onclick=` can't find the method.

Comment: but when i redefined the test() function in document ready, outside the ajax success callback, why does the onclick still unable to see it?

Comment: because it's then in the *scope* of document ready.  Generally, if it's inside `{ }` then onclick won't be able to see it.  If you use jquery event binding, then it wouldn't be an issue, but you're using `onclick=` which needs functions defined at the global level (or namespaced, but that's another issue).

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to attach the test function for dynamically add button and remove test() function from the Ajax request

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnHistory", function(){
  alert ('test');
});
```

Remove onclick attribute from button

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this function on your script

```
function test() {
    alert('working');
//    your code
}
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class attribute to the dynamically added button and add the onclick jquery function to the buttons. Use this code.

History

use the jquery function like this

`$(document).on("click", ".btn-history", function(){
  alert ('test');
});`

or

`$('#table-id').on("click", ".btn-history", function(){
  alert ('test');
});`

Answer (score 0):

I have written jQuery to enable external function. and also you need to write call function in it, if the data is binding dynamically `$(document).on("click", "#btnHistory", function(){ });`

in your code you are looking for function and enabling click meted but data is blinded later and click method is not ready to trigger so if you use above  jQuery will solve issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').on('click',function(){
    alert('test');
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {      
    //test();
    $('#bindTable').append('<table class="table table-striped"><tr><td>Id</td><td>Pic Name</td><td>' +
             '<button type="button"  id="btnHistory" class="btn btn-success">History</button> ' + 
             ' <button id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> ' +
             ' <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> ' + 
             '</td></tr></table>');
  }
});
function test(){
  alert ('test');
}
$(document).on("click", "#btnHistory", function(){
  test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="bindTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function inline will only work from global scope, so defined it outside of the success callback. Or alternatively you could just attach the listener dynamically, like so:

```
$(.test).off('click').on('click', test)
```

And then your `test()` function could be defined in global scope. You can add the `off('click')` to make sure only one listener is on the buttons at all times. Perhaps a more performant option, however could be the following:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.test')) {
        // call test() here
    }
})
```

This way, only a single listener needs to be attached and it does not have to be re-attached when new buttons are added.